# get relative path from url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get relative path from url. http://test.com/my/path --> /my/path.

I tried the following:

```js
url = 'http://test.com/my/path';
console.log(url.replace(/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*/));
```

I am getting undefined/my/path

Any help on why I am getting undefined? or what is wrong with my Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the second argument for `replace()` (empty string in your case)

```js
url = 'http://test.com/my/path';
console.log(url.replace(/^(?:\/\/|[^\/]+)*/, ''));
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to just use the [native URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to extract the pathname:

```
>>> new URL('http://test.com/my/path').pathname
'/my/path'
```

Comment: nice, something new learnt

Answer (score 0):

You should use the URL API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
let url = new URL('http://test.com/my/path');

url object: 
href: "http://test.com/my/path"
origin: "http://test.com"
protocol: "http:"
username: ""
password: ""
host: "test.com"
hostname: "test.com"
port: ""
pathname: "/my/path"
search: ""
searchParams: URLSearchParams {}
```

You are after the `pathname` property.